# PHP what does this means App::instance()->init($_REQUEST)?

Tags: php, cs-cart

my `run.php` file contains

```php
use Installer\App;

include 'app/Installer/App.php';
App::instance()->init($_REQUEST);
```

And `app.php` contains two function `instance()` and `init($param = array())`.

Why a function is called by another function??

Comment: This means that `App` is initalized with any params passed to the script. I guess `instance` is a dynamic object owned by the static class `App`.

Comment: This is called method chaining. The `instance` object returns its self as an instance, and then allows you to execute against that instance the init. This is likely done to check if the instance has  already been created previously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`App::instance()` - it's just call to static class method named 'instance' (it's seems like use of Singleton pattern, so i suppose it returns some instance of 'App' class).

`init($_REQUEST)` - is a call to an instance method of class of object that returned by instance() method.

You can split this calls to different code lines for better understanding:

```
$instance = App::instance();
$instance->init($_REQUEST);
```

It's not a "function called by another function", it's just little piece of object-oriented programming.

Comment: Specifically, it's [method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, yep.. Pretty popular technique, that can sometimes enhance code readability, but also will give you tricky debugging and refactoring as downside. I personally hate it, but do it anyway, because of laziness for naming variables and writing additional code :)